# Sharepoint GetFileByServerRelativeUrl return document does not exist

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to call the SharePoint Api's through POSTMAN to get a document. 
When calling these two urls:

```
https://<MY_SITE>.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Documents/testFolder/Document.docx')/$value

https://<MY_SITE>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Documents/testFolder/Document.docx')/$value
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The file /sites/Test/Documents/testFolder/Document.docx 
                       does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the library Documents the default documents when we create sites? If so, you should use Shared%20Documents in your rest api. Like this:

```
GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Shared%20Documents/testFolder/Document.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked by going to GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/testFolder/Document.docx')